Как можно NATировать IP адрес средствами NGINX?
Задача следующая.
Нужно настроить профиль nginx таким образом, чтобы запрос во внешний интернет NATировал IP.
То есть подменял настоящий IP на IP из белого списка.
Внимание, вопрос:
можно ли это организовать средствами NGINX, и если да, то прошу примерную схему .conf файла

Как связан nginx и запрос во внешний интернет (и что вы под этим вообще имеете в виду)?

Есть сеть тачек , они все бщаются по внутренней сети.. но хочу чтобы выход во внещнюю сеть был через единую тачку nginx, которая подменяла бы внутренний ip адрес на реальный ip

Это называется gateway, и nginx для этого совершенно не нужен. У вас роутер дома именно так работает
